SequelizeAssociationError: Conflict in defining HasMany and BelongsTo relationships between User and Friends models
I am trying to define a HasMany and BelongsTo relationship between my User and Friends models in Sequelize. However, I am encountering the following error when I start my server:
AssociationError [SequelizeAssociationError]: Defining HasMany association "friendRequestsReceived" from User to Friends failed

The association "friendRequestsReceived" needs to define the BelongsTo association "user" from Friends to User, but that child association has already been defined as BelongsTo, to User by this call:

User.hasMany(Friends, {
    foreignKey: { name: 'user_id' },
    as: 'friendRequestsSent',
    hooks: false,
    name: { plural: 'friendRequestsSent', singular: 'friendRequestsSent' }
})

That association would be re-used if compatible, but it is incompatible because their options are not reconcilable:
...

What I am trying to achieve:
I want to implement a friend request system where:

Each user can send multiple friend requests (friendRequestsSent).
Each user can receive multiple friend requests (friendRequestsReceived).
Here is the relevant structure of my User and Friends models:

User model:
User.hasMany(Friends, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    as: 'friendRequestsSent', 
});

User.hasMany(Friends, {
    foreignKey: 'friend_id',
    as: 'friendRequestsReceived', 
});

Friends Model:
Friends.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'user_id',
    as: 'sender', 
});

Friends.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: 'friend_id',
    as: 'receiver', 
});

My Question:
How can I correctly define HasMany and BelongsTo relationships for my User and Friends models so that:
A user can have both sent and received friend requests.
Sequelize doesn’t throw this association conflict error.
Is there a better way to structure these relationships in Sequelize? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you!

Looks like a Sequelize bug unless you imported both model modules to each other (having circular dependencies).

@Anatoly do you know how to resolve this bug because i didn't import both modules to each other?
User model imports:
const sequelize = require('../config/db.js'); const { DataTypes } = require('@sequelize/core'); const Permission = require('./Permissions.js');
Friends model imports:
const { DataTypes } = require('@sequelize/core'); const sequelize = require('../config/db.js'); const User = require('./User');

Please add model definitions with imports int he post (as code blocks)
